# How to access Buxfer using their API when I signed up using my Google account

Tags: api, google-signin

I am trying to use the [Buxfer API](https://www.buxfer.com/help/api) which has the following login function

```
https://www.buxfer.com/api/login?userid=john@doe.com&password=dohdoh
```

The problem is I signed up to Buxfer using my google account, so I have no idea what to put in here.

Is there some standard way of accessing APIs for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  By going into the settings I can still set a password on my account.  I used that password with my gmail email address and the rest interface logged in ok.